# Can I force the implementors of an Interface to apply certain attribute on a member?

Tags: vb.net, oop, interface, attributes

In VB.NET, can I do something like:

```
Interface X
    <SomeAttrib> _
    SomeProp as String
End Interface
```

which would force any class implementing X to also apply SomeAttrib on SomeProp and result in compile (or run)-time error otherwise.

```
Class XBox
    Implements X

    Public SomeProp as String Implements X.SomeProp
        ...
    End Property
End Interface
```

The above should give error as `SomeProp` doesn't apply `SomeAttrib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, attributes aren't part of the signature that's enforced by an interface.

If this is a custom property, you might want to make whatever's looking for it check whether the type implements an interface and fetch the attributes from there instead.

Or you could always write a unit test to validate all implementations, if they're under your control - something between a compile-time check and a normal execution-time check...